# Executing Javascript from Objective C in Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm using cordova 6.5.0 and I'm creating a plugin from which I would like to execute some javascript.

I have found in forums that from my webview I can use stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString but it can not be recognised as a valid method.

For instance in AppDelegate.m, just for testing, I've tried the following:

```
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString]:@"alert('Test')"];
```

but I receive the message "No visible @inteface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString'".

I have created a class object named Utils.m

```
@implementation Utils: NSObject

id webview;
id delegate;


-(void) initialise:(id) wbview Delegate:(id) dlg{

    webview = wbview;
    delegate = dlg;

}

-(void) executeJavascript:(NSString *)str{

    [delegate runInBackground:^{

        [delegate stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('test')"];


    }];

}
```

And then from the cordova plugin from pluginInitialize I have

```
- (void)pluginInitialize{


    /* Start pjsua app thread */
//    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pjsuaStart) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    utils = [[Utils alloc] init ];
    [utils initialise:self.webView Delegate:self.commandDelegate];

    [utils executeJavascript:@"alert('Test');"];

}
```

Although for some reason the stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString is considered a valid method, the application crashes...

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Symeon

Answer (score 1):

Use `evalJs` not `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`:

```
[delegate evalJs:@"alert('test')"];
```